# Do you get separate certificates for CFI and CFII?

Tags: faa, pilot-certification, cfi

I passed my CFII checkride the same month my CFI was to expire. So far I have only received a new CFI card in the mail. Shouldn’t I be receiving a card that says CFII on it as well, or should the card I received have read CFII? Are there two separate cards?

Comment: If you did it the same month, you probably won't get the CFII card for a while, it takes time to run through the system, especially given COVID shutdowns.

Comment: Welcome to aviation.SE! I edited your question to (hopefully) make it a little clearer; if I got something wrong then you can just edit again or roll back. And it may seem like an obvious question, but are you asking about the US? I don't know if other countries use the CFI/CFII terminology too. For questions about qualifications, regulations etc. it's always best to tell which country or regulations you're asking about. Finally, if you're new to the site the [tour] may be helpful.

Answer (score 3):

No.  Under ratings on the backside of the Flight Instructor certificate, it should say:

FLIGHT INSTRUCTOR

AIRPLANE SINGLE ENGINE, INSTRUMENT AIRPLANE.

This is a CFI, CFII Flight Instructor Certificate, assuming you did your training in the United States under the FAA’s system.

You should see the same ratings on your temp certificate as well.

Comment: There is no CFI certificate with ASEL on it.  It is classified as ASE or Airplane Single Engine.  You are legal to teach both land and sea planes by passing one practical test provided you have the appropriate class on your pilot certificate.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is found in the FARs.  You will receive a new CFI certificate with the appropriate category and class rating with an instrument rating.  The FAA moniker on the front of the certificate will change from black to blue to indicate a certificate with instrument privileges.

> **§61.5   Certificates and ratings issued under this part.**
>
> (a) The following certificates are issued under this part to an applicant who satisfactorily accomplishes the training and certification requirements for the certificate sought:
>
> > (1) Pilot certificates—
> >
> > > (i) Student pilot.
> > >
> > > (ii) Sport pilot.
> > >
> > > (iii) Recreational pilot.
> > >
> > > (iv) Private pilot.
> > >
> > > (v) Commercial pilot.
> > >
> > > (vi) Airline transport pilot.
> >
> > (2) Flight instructor certificates.
> >
> > (3) Ground instructor certificates.
>
> (b) The following ratings are placed on a pilot certificate (other than student pilot) when an applicant satisfactorily accomplishes the training and certification requirements for the rating sought:
>
> > (1) Aircraft category ratings—
> >
> > > (i) Airplane.
> > >
> > > (ii) Rotorcraft.
> > >
> > > (iii) Glider.
> > >
> > > (iv) Lighter-than-air.
> > >
> > > (v) Powered-lift.
> > >
> > > (vi) Powered parachute.
> > >
> > > (vii) Weight-shift-control aircraft.
> >
> > (2) Airplane class ratings—
> >
> > > (i) Single-engine land.
> > >
> > > (ii) Multiengine land.
> > >
> > > (iii) Single-engine sea.
> > >
> > > (iv) Multiengine sea.
> >
> > (3) Rotorcraft class ratings—
> >
> > > (i) Helicopter.
> > >
> > > (ii) Gyroplane.
> >
> > (4) Lighter-than-air class ratings—
> >
> > > (i) Airship.
> > >
> > > (ii) Balloon.
> >
> > (5) Weight-shift-control aircraft class ratings—
> >
> > > (i) Weight-shift-control aircraft land.
> > >
> > > (ii) Weight-shift-control aircraft sea.
> >
> > (6) Powered parachute class ratings—
> >
> > > (i) Powered parachute land.
> > >
> > > (ii) Powered parachute sea.
> >
> > (7) Aircraft type ratings—
> >
> > > (i) Large aircraft other than lighter-than-air.
> > >
> > > (ii) Turbojet-powered airplanes.
> > >
> > > (iii) Other aircraft type ratings specified by the Administrator through the aircraft type certification procedures.
> > >
> > > (iv) Second-in-command pilot type rating for aircraft that is certificated for operations with a minimum crew of at least two pilots.
> >
> > (8) Instrument ratings (on private and commercial pilot certificates only)—
> >
> > > (i) Instrument—Airplane.
> > >
> > > (ii) Instrument—Helicopter.
> > >
> > > (iii) Instrument—Powered-lift.
>
> **(c) The following ratings are placed on a flight instructor certificate when an applicant satisfactorily accomplishes the training and certification requirements for the rating sought:**
>
> > (1) **Aircraft category ratings—**
> >
> > > (i) Airplane.
> > >
> > > (ii) Rotorcraft.
> > >
> > > (iii) Glider.
> > >
> > > (iv) Powered-lift.
> >
> > (2) **Airplane class ratings—**
> >
> > > (i) Single-engine.
> > >
> > > (ii) Multiengine.
> >
> > (3) **Rotorcraft class ratings—**
> >
> > > (i) Helicopter.
> > >
> > > (ii) Gyroplane.
> >
> > **(4) Instrument ratings—**
> >
> > > (i) Instrument—Airplane.
> > >
> > > (ii) Instrument—Helicopter.
> > >
> > > (iii) Instrument—Powered-lift.
> >
> > (5) Sport pilot rating.
>
> (d) The following ratings are placed on a ground instructor certificate when an applicant satisfactorily accomplishes the training and certification requirements for the rating sought:
>
> > (1) Basic.
> >
> > (2) Advanced.
> >
> > (3) Instrument.